# function call with argument in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included an external javascript file whose contents are:

```
function getTopNews(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response){
        alert("Got top news!");
    },

    error: function(){
        alert("There was an error!");
    },

    complete: function(){
        alert('Executed');
    }
  });
}
```

Now the above javascript file is included in another file where I have written this code:

```
$(document).ready(getTopNews);  // works
```

Now suppose my getTopNews is defined like getTopNews(var newsId), then how should I call it? I have tried following and it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(getTopNews(26));  // does not work

$(document).ready(fucntion(){  // does not work
  $(this).getTopNews(26)
});
```

Both of these do not work for me. Help!

Comment: You have a typo (fucnition), maybe that's why it's not working? Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: @bfavaretto: Good one, but that typo is here, not in actual code :D

Comment: The tip about the browser console is still valid though. **Always** check that, it will catch all syntax errors like `getTopNews(var newsId)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Now suppose my `getTopNews` is defined like `getTopNews(var newsId)`"*

Then what you'd have is a syntax error and the code wouldn't work. Remove the `var`:

```
function getTopNews(newsId) {
   // your code here
}
```

To call that on ready, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getTopNews(26);
});
```

Note that in your code when you did something similar you had a typo on this line:

```
$(document).ready(fucntion(){  // does not work
```

...where you spelled `function` as `fucntion`.

Note that both problems should've been reported in your browser's console.

Comment: Thanks @bfavaretto, I didn't notice that at first.

Answer (score 4):

What abt this ? `getTopNews` isnt an object of `document` so it wont come under `$(this)` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getTopNews(26);
});
```

Comment: @stalin any console erros?

Comment: getTopNews function have to be defined before you call it. If it's the case, this answer works for sure.

Comment: _"`getTopNews` isnt an object of `document` so it wont come under `$(this)`"_ - Even if it was a _property_ of `document` it still wouldn't be accessible from `$(this)`, because `$(this)` returns a jQuery object, not `document`.

Comment: I am including the js containing getTopNews() function before $(document).ready(), it works without argument but not with argument.

Comment: @passionateCoder: your method not even works without argument!

Comment: @passionateCoder: you are correct. this is the correct way. 'var' was the problem